# conditions for asymptotic comparison to hold

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, steady-state

I have the following simple dynamical system:
\begin{align}
x_1' &= a - f(x_2)x_1\\
x_2' &= bx_1 - cx_2,
\end{align}
where all parameters and initial conditions are positive. $f(x_2)$ is a positive and increasing function with respect to $x_2$. Suppose I want to study the asymptotic behavior of this system and decide to do the following.

First, I note that the more $x_1$ I have, the more higher the production rate for $x_2$ will be. Secondly, I note that the larger $x_2$, the higher $f(x_2)$ would be. Thus I choose to replace $f(x_2)$ by a function $g(x_1)$ such that:

1. $g(x_1) > 0$ and $\frac{dg}{x_1} > 0$.
2. $g(x_1)$ gives the same fixed points for $x_1$ (perhaps through something like a quasi-steady-state-approximation for $x_2$).

Together, I obtain:
\begin{equation}
x_1' = a - g(x_1)x_1.
\end{equation}

Due to the construction, the asymptotic behavior of $x_1$ in this equation should be the same as that of $x_1$ in the original equation. I tried this out with $f$ and $g$ being simple hill equation and it works. My question is: what may render this method invalid?

Comment: The interesting behavior occurs only on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$. The unique equilibrium $(x^*_1,x^*_2)$ is globally asymptotically stable. Why? First, any solution eventually enters $R:=[0,\frac{f(0)}a+1,\frac{b}c(\frac{f(0)}a+1)+1]$, second, the [Bendixson–Dulac theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem) gives that there are no nonconstant periodic solutions in $R$. As there is only one equilibrium in $R$, which is (locally) asymptotically stable, the equilibrium is globally asymptotically stable. Can you fill the details?

Comment: @user539887 I understand the global stability part. I also used Bendixon-Dulac criterion to show global stability in both cases. However, my question is more on when does this not hold? Or if there is a rigorous way of going about this.